# Flutter Web App Error - Could not find the correct Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am getting the following error when using Provider in a WebApp. I've seen this before when creating none webapps and can usually fix it. However I can't see where the error is within the webapp. I am creating the MultiProvider in Main.dart and above the MaterialApp widget.
Here is the error:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List> above this CategoryWidget Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.

And my MultiProvider code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return FutureBuilder(
    future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      // Check for errors
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text('ERROR: DID NOT INITIALIZE FIREBASE!')),
          ),
        );
      }

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        print("FIREBASE INITIALIZED");
        final catCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('categories')
            .orderBy("active", descending: true);
        final categories = catCollection.snapshots().map((snapShot) =>
            snapShot.docs
                .map((catDoc) => Category.fromMap(catDoc.data(), catDoc.id))
                .toList());

        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            StreamProvider<User?>(
              create: (_) => FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
              initialData: null,
            ),
            StreamProvider<List<Category?>>(
              create: (_) => categories,
              initialData: [],
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Categories(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Auth(),
            ),
          ],
          child: MaterialApp(
            title: "Qi Gang's Dashboard",
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            // home: LoginSignupScreen(isLoginForm: true),
            initialRoute: LoginSignupScreen.id,
            routes: {
              LoginSignupScreen.id: (context) =>
                  LoginSignupScreen(isLoginForm: true),
              MainScaffold.id: (context) => MainScaffold(),
```

And lower down the widget tree, called from MainScaffold is my CategoryWidget, where the error is occurring:

```
Widget categoryGrid(BuildContext context) {

  final categories = Provider.of<List<Category>>(context);
```

Been trying to solve this for some time now and am blocked so would really appreciate it if you could point out where I am going wrong here.

Many thanks

Comment: have restarted or re-run your app and tried?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I have done that several times. But still gives the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in providers official documentation. [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#reading-a-value)

```
context.watch<T>(), which makes the widget listen to changes on T
context.read<T>(), which returns T without listening to it
context.select<T, R>(R cb(T value)), which allows a widget to listen to only a small part of T.
```

These methods will look up in the widget tree starting from the widget associated with the BuildContext passed and will `return the nearest variable of type T` found (or throw if nothing is found).

and in your code you are defining `<List<Category?>>` in provider and you are Looking for `<List<Category>>` down the widget tree thus this is giving you error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add provider (or initialize) to main.dart and then try to use it.
It will work surely.